# Why AIDL is designed NOT able to sent exceptions back to the caller

Tags: android, aidl

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

> No exceptions that you throw are sent back to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its using linux/unix RPC calls (that's why you can use AIDL to access other processes), and RPC calls don't have the idea of exceptions-  they were written for C back in the 70s.  And it would be complicated to make them.   How exceptions work under the hood is INCREDIBLY nasty.  Its basically longjmp calls.  Doing that around a process switch... it's doable, but it would require messing with the return type of every AIDL function to return basically an untyped parameter with a flag saying what the actual type was, and code to parse that and rethrow on the client side.  And it wouldn't work for generic Exceptions, it would only work for Exception classes defined in AIDL, which throws out the entire built in Exception hierarchy.  And it would make it impossible for an NDK library to use AIDL, because you'd pretty much have to then go through their deserialize libraries to make it work.  Too much work for too little reward, given the extreme rarity of AIDL and the fact that anyone using it probably knows how to return an error value if needed.